# change style of each item in listbox C# Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I want to change the style of each item in the listbox like this

[image]

But in my case, I want only to change the color and font style (italic, bold) of each item, the items in the listbox is added programmatically

how could I change the style of each item?

Comment: Perhaps you can use ValueConverters at the Color and FontStyle properties in this case. Like this you can convert a specific object or value to the desired color or fontstyle.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view model class for the data items that has all necessary properties, like

```
class DataItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Brush Foreground { get; set; }
    public FontStyle FontStyle { get; set; }
    public FontWeight FontWeight { get; set; }
}
```

and bind to these properties in the ItemTemplate of the ListBox. The example below assumes that `Items` is a property in your view model that returns a collection of DataItem objects.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
                       Foreground="{Binding Foreground}"
                       FontStyle="{Binding FontStyle}"
                       FontWeight="{Binding FontWeight}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

---

If you prefer to use boolean properties like e.g. `IsBold` in your item view model, you may add an `ItemContainerStyle` with DataTriggers that set the appropriate ListBoxItem properties:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
                       Foreground="{Binding Foreground}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsItalic}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBold}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: @ clemens.. A curious question Is it a right way to bring Brush,FontStyle etc to Model or ViewModel?

Comment: I would say it depends. If you already have data that determines whether text should be styled (for example a boolean `IsBold`) I'd very much recommend a ValueConverter for this purpose. If not, this approach is right aswell.

Comment: @Clemens Alright, I can agree with DataTriggers aswell ;)